# Insert doesn't work on SQL Server but no error

Tags: php, sql-server, triggers

I'm working on someone's else database creating a simple PHP solution, running Apache (XAMPP+Windows 2003 Server) that connects to a MS SQL SERVER database running Windows 2008 R2.

I've been working a few days, I've created a few tables, I've inserted data on those tables, but now I'm trying to insert data into an existing table using PHP, but for this table in particular the insert statement doesn't work at all, but there is no error message.

Here is the code.

```
    <?php

    include '../../includes/mssql.php';

    $insereItem = "INSERT INTO TBL_NOTAS_FATURAMENTO_ITENS (CD_LANCAMENTO   ......... ) VALUES (26452,.....0)";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $insereItem);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

echo $insereItem . "\n";

?>
```

There is no error message.

As you can see I've removed data from the insert statement so it doesn't use too much space here (there are 88 values to be inserted). There is no error message, there is no error in Apache logs, there is no error in php logs but the data is not commited.

As you can see I did a "echo" to the statement, so if I copy and paste the statement in SQL Server Management Studio the insert works as it should, but if I try commiting with PHP it won't work.

The table I'm trying to insert data has an insert trigger and I'm pretty sure that this is the problem because if I disable the trigger then the insert works as it should (so there is no error in building up the insert command).

I've already tried to use other sqlsrv_ commands, using the begin connection, prepare, execute and then commit, and the result is the same. The sqlsrv_execute returns true, sqlsrv_prepare returns

PS: the real code isn't the one above, since the real code uses an array to parse parameters, but the final insert statement is the same, and the problem happens either way.

Here's the code to the insert trigger: (as I said before, the database was not built by me)

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER  TRIGGER [TRG_TBL_NOTAS_FATURAMENTO_ITENS_REGINSERIR] ON [dbo].[TBL_NOTAS_FATURAMENTO_ITENS] 
FOR INSERT
AS

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 'TRUE' FROM INSERTED)
        BEGIN

--SET NOCOUNT ON
--IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 RETURN

            DECLARE @CD_LANCAMENTO      AS INT
            DECLARE @CD_FILIAL          AS INT
            DECLARE @CD_ITEM            AS INT
            DECLARE @CD_CME             AS INT
            DECLARE @CD_MATERIAL        AS INT
            DECLARE @CD_EMPRESA         AS INT
            DECLARE @CD_ID              AS INT
            DECLARE @DT_EMISSAO         AS DATETIME

            SELECT @CD_LANCAMENTO =     (SELECT CD_LANCAMENTO   FROM INSERTED)
            SELECT @CD_EMPRESA =        (SELECT CD_EMPRESA      FROM DBO.TBL_NOTAS_FATURAMENTO   WHERE (CD_LANCAMENTO = @CD_LANCAMENTO))
            SELECT @CD_FILIAL =         (SELECT CD_FILIAL       FROM DBO.TBL_NOTAS_FATURAMENTO   WHERE (CD_LANCAMENTO = @CD_LANCAMENTO))
            SELECT @CD_ITEM =           (SELECT CD_ITEM         FROM INSERTED)
            SELECT @CD_CME =            (SELECT CD_CME          FROM INSERTED)
            SELECT @CD_MATERIAL =       (SELECT CD_MATERIAL     FROM INSERTED)
            SELECT @CD_ID =             (SELECT CD_ID           FROM INSERTED)
            SELECT @DT_EMISSAO =        (SELECT DT_EMISSAO      FROM DBO.TBL_NOTAS_FATURAMENTO   WHERE (CD_LANCAMENTO = @CD_LANCAMENTO))

            --CALCULA IMPOSTOS
            EXEC SP_CALCULA_IMPOSTOS_NOTAS_FATURAMENTO @CD_LANCAMENTO, @CD_ITEM, @CD_CME, @CD_MATERIAL

            --TOTAL DO LANCAMENTO
            EXEC SP_TOTAL_NOTAS_FATURAMENTO @CD_LANCAMENTO

            --ATUALIZA VOLUMES
            EXEC SP_CALCULA_VOLUMES_NOTAS_FATURAMENTO @CD_LANCAMENTO, @CD_EMPRESA

            --ATUALIZA KARDEX
            EXEC SP_CALCULA_ESTOQUE 41, @CD_LANCAMENTO, @CD_ID, @DT_EMISSAO, @CD_FILIAL, @CD_MATERIAL

        END
```

Comment: How can you be sure (a) you're connecting to the right server (b) you're connecting to the right database (c) you're connecting to the right version of the table (one could be `dbo.TBL_...`, another could be `some_other_schema.TBL_...`)? How have you validated that the connection string and the table you're checking are the exact same thing between your PHP code and Management Studio? What does the trigger do? Can you show that code?

Comment: If the insert works with the trigger disabled, then that is likely the culprit. If you post the trigger code then likely someone can point out the issue.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Here we go: (a): yes, as written the insert works in other tables, only in this one it's not working. The connection string is the same I'm using in other queries. (b) yes, it's the right database since other queries work as expected. (c) yes, the statement is correct because if I disable the trigger the data is inserted in the right table :) Also I've tried using the [nGestao].[dbo].[TBL_NOTAS_FATURAMENTO_ITENS] in the query to be sure that it's the right database and the right table as suggested.

Comment: Without even looking at the logic more closely, your trigger has a common, fatal flaw: it is written with the assumption that every insert will be a single-row insert.

Comment: @Juliano did you find the solution? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: Patricia, I don't remeber now how I solved this, but if I'm not mistaken I disabled the triggers using the DISABLE TRIGGER command and then the error message came up, it was something in the SQL format with quotes or something like that.